# Как перехватить обновление страницы и перенаправить на другой url?

Tags: javascript

https://canaho.ca/qualify-index/home-owner
как на этом сайте при переключении форм меняется урл у сайта, но если обновить страницу идёт переадресация на главную

Answer (score 1):

На `canaho.ca` навигация полностью происходит на клиентской стороне при помощи history API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState). Третий параметр позволяет менять URL без запроса страницы с сервера.

Когда страница загружается, извлекается последнее состояние из history state, если его нет - идет переход на "домашнюю" страницу, в нашем случае `home-owner` (опять же при помощи `pushState` или `replaceState`).

Вместе с этим, на сервере настроена отдача одной и той же страницы независимо от URL (конкретная настройка такого подхода зависит от сервера).

---

Стоит отметить, что есть не один способ добиться такого результата, с навигацией на серверной стороне в том числе.